# Split rows based on overlapping dates and update start and end dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Edited to cover all cases

I am relatively new to SQL (SQL Server 2008) and I have the problem statement as below. The data in the table can contain overlapping time durations, but this needs to be separated out (Below sample dataset)

The data present in table is as below:

```
Column 1    |Column 2   |StartTime  |EndTime    |Factor

  A           |B          |Jan 1      |Jun  30     |0.7
  A           |B          |Feb 1      |September 30|0.3
  A           |B          |Mar  1     |August   31 |0.2
```

The desired output is as follows:

```
 Column 1   |Column 2   |StartTime  |EndTime    |Factor
   A         |B           |Jan  1    |Jan 31    |0.7
   A         |B           |Feb 1     |Feb 28    |1.0
   A         |B           |Mar 1     |Jun 30    |1.2
   A         |B           |Jul 1     |August 31 |0.5
   A         |B           |Sept 1    |Sept 30   |0.3
```

Requirement is that whenever Column 1 and Column 2 are the same and the dates overlap, the factor should be summed up, and a new record should be created with a new start and end time, such that there is a continuity.

The Start and End time are in DATETIME format.

I tried using self joins but did not reach anywhere. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: its the same output and data presented.. any details?

Comment: how is mar to june factor cacluated

Comment: what are your start and end times held as?  Are they dates or just text?  If they are text then is there a year held?  I believe the questioner wants to add the factors together where there is an overlap.  So if you had a table of months, 1-12, you could sum all the factors falling in that range (albeit that the data shown uses text for month names).  Recombining sums for 1-12 is an 'island' problem, that can be solved using WITH, row_number, a self join to previous row, then detection of points of change.

Comment: Start time and end time are dates format, should have mentioned that earlier. @AndrewDeighton

Comment: What if more than two periods overlapped? e.g. let's add to your example period: `Feb-Sep, factor= 0.3`. What would be the result?

Comment: March to June is calculated because March and June are part of both the rows in the input. Hence, the factor sums up as 0.7+0.2 = 0.9

Comment: If more than two periods overlapped, then it would sum that up too, so if Feb-Sep is factor 0.3, then output would be:

Comment: @AshokChandran please, add this source row to your question and update desired output.

Comment: @IvanStarostin done!

Comment: Answer easy but question hard.. Question is not clear.

Comment: Are the periods always months? E.g. could you have StartDate=20160315 and EndDate=20160905

Comment: Nope, start date would always be first of the month, and end date would be last day of the month @tomislav_t

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @MD AS int;

SELECT @MD = MAX(YEAR(a2.STARTTIME) * 100 + MONTH(a2.ENDTIME)) FROM ashtable a2;

WITH MTHS AS    (
                    SELECT MIN(YEAR(STARTTIME) * 100 + MONTH(STARTTIME)) TheMonth FROM ashtable
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT TheMonth + 1  FROM MTHS WHERE TheMonth < @MD
                ),
     ALLMONTHS AS 
                (
                    select a.Column1,a.column2,m.TheMonth, SUM(FACTOR) f from mths m 
                                LEFT JOIN 
                                    ashtable a 
                                        ON m.TheMonth >= YEAR(a.STARTTIME) * 100 + MONTH(a.STARTTIME) 
                                        AND 
                                        m.TheMonth <= YEAR(a.ENDTIME) * 100 + MONTH(a.ENDTIME)
                        GROUP BY a.Column1,a.column2, m.TheMonth
                ),
     RNS AS
                (SELECT  a.Column1,a.column2,a.TheMonth, a.f, a.f - COALESCE(b.f, -99999999.99) dif FROM ALLMONTHS a 
                                        LEFT JOIN ALLMONTHS b ON a.TheMonth = b.TheMonth + 1 AND a.column1=b.column1 and a.column2=b.column2),   
    ISLANDS AS (
                select  a.Column1,a.column2,a.TheMonth, 
                        MIN(b.TheMonth) MonthEnd, 
                        MIN(A.f) Factor 
                                from RNS a 
                                    LEFT JOIN RNS b ON a.column1=b.column1 and a.column2=b.column2 and b.TheMonth > a.TheMonth AND b.f <> a.f WHERE a.dif <> 0
                                GROUP BY a.column1,a.column2,a.TheMonth
                )               
    SELECT  Column1,column2,dateadd(month, (themonth - 1) % 100, 
            DateADD(year,(Themonth) / 100 - 1900, 0)) s, 
            dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month, (themonth) % 100, 
            DateADD(year,(Themonth) / 100 - 1900, 0))) e, factor  FROM ISLANDS order by column1,column2,s
```

my output (including a test row for different column keys)

```
    Column1    column2    s                       e                       factor
---------- ---------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -------
A          B          2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 2016-01-31 00:00:00.000 0.7
A          B          2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 2016-02-29 00:00:00.000 1.0
A          B          2016-03-01 00:00:00.000 2016-03-31 00:00:00.000 1.2
A          B          2016-07-01 00:00:00.000 2016-07-31 00:00:00.000 0.5
A          B          2016-09-01 00:00:00.000 2016-09-30 00:00:00.000 0.3
A          C          2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 2016-01-31 00:00:00.000 99.0
```

here is a modified version, throwing away my failed ideas of representing year month as an integer

```
    DECLARE @MD AS datetime;

SELECT @MD = MAX(endtime) FROM ashtable a2;

WITH MTHS AS    (
                    SELECT MIN(STARTTIME) TheMonth FROM ashtable
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT dateadd(month,1,TheMonth) TheMonth  FROM MTHS WHERE TheMonth < @MD
                ),

     ALLMONTHS AS 
                (
                    select a.Column1,a.column2,m.TheMonth, SUM(FACTOR) f from mths m 
                                LEFT JOIN 
                                    ashtable a 
                                        ON m.TheMonth >= a.starttime
                                        AND 
                                        m.TheMonth < a.endtime 
                        GROUP BY a.Column1,a.column2, m.TheMonth
                ),
     RNS AS
                (SELECT  a.Column1,a.column2,a.TheMonth, a.f, a.f - COALESCE(b.f, -99999999.99) dif FROM ALLMONTHS a 
                                        LEFT JOIN ALLMONTHS b ON a.TheMonth = dateadd(month,1,b.TheMonth) AND a.column1=b.column1 and a.column2=b.column2),  
    ISLANDS AS (
                select  a.Column1,a.column2,a.TheMonth,dq2.lastmonth,a.f factor
                    from RNS a
                    CROSS APPLY
                        (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (SELECT 1 as ord, b.TheMonth lastmonth FROM RNS b WHERE a.Column1 = b.column1 and a.column2=b.column2 and b.themonth>a.themonth and a.f <> b.f 
                        union SELECT 2 as ord, dateadd(month,1,max(c.themonth)) lastmonth  from rns c where a.Column1 = c.column1 and a.column2=c.column2) dq ORDER BY DQ.ord) dq2
                        where a.dif<>0
                        --MIN(b.TheMonth) MonthEnd, 
                        --MIN(A.f) Factor 
                        --      from RNS a 
                        --          LEFT JOIN RNS b ON a.column1=b.column1 and a.column2=b.column2 and b.TheMonth > a.TheMonth AND b.f <> a.f where a.dif<>0
                        --      GROUP BY a.column1,a.column2,a.TheMonth
                )   


    SELECT  Column1,column2,themonth, dateadd(day,-1,lastmonth),
             factor  FROM ISLANDS order by column1,column2,themonth
```

Comment: The solution looks great, except there seems to be no continuity, i.e., the third row should have ideally ended at 2016-06-30. Will go through the code again and see if this can be changed, thanks for the start though.